# create table of contents in python

Tags: python

Assuming the following text:

```
# Algorithms
This chapter covers the most basic algorithms.
## Sorting
Quicksort is fast and widely used in practice
Merge sort is a deterministic algorithm
## Searching
DFS and BFS are widely used graph searching algorithms
# Data Structures
more text
## more data structures
```

How would i create a table of contents in python that if the line starts with `#` I would replace with `1.` for the first `#`. If the line starts with `##` I would replace with `1.1.` the second time in the text a `#` would be seen I need to replace with `2.` and so on:

```
1. Algorithms
1.1. Sorting
1.2. Searching
2. Data Structures
2.1 more data structures
```

I would begin doing something like :

```
for line in text:
 if line.startswith('#'):
      ....
```

but I dont know how to proceed.

Comment: You'll need to keep track of the level of `#`. Using something like a stack and comparing the length of the stack to the number of `#` in the line you're on and deciding if you should increment the last number or pop, or append a number should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

levels = defaultdict(int)
max_level = 0
index = []
for line in text:
    if not line.startswith("#"):
        continue
    hashes, caption = line.rstrip().split(maxsplit=1)
    level = len(hashes)
    max_level = max(level, max_level)
    levels[level] += 1
    for l in range(level + 1, max_level + 1):
        levels[l] = 0
    index.append(
        ".".join(str(levels[l]) for l in range(1, level+1))
        + ". " + caption
    )
```

Some expanations:

- `levels` stores the current state of the counter of the table of contents. It's a `defaultdict(int)` because its values are `int`s and that makes it easy to use.
- `max_level` stores the maximal depth of the counter *so far*. (E.g.: In the step from only single `#`s to the first `##` the maximal depth increases (`1->2`).)
- If a line of the text startswith `#` then it is split in 2 parts: 1. the hashes and 2. the caption.
- The number of hashes (`len(hashes)`) is the level-depth of the *current* entry. Just in case it increases the maximum depth *so far*, `max_level` gets an update (often doing nothing).
- Then the counter for the *current* level is increaed by `1`, and all the counters for the levels *beyond the current one* get a reset to `0`. (E.g.: If the last state of the counter was `1.2` and then the first level gets increased (`#`), not only must the counter switch the first place (`1->2`) but also the second level needs a reset (`2->0`).) Another would be to delete those levels.
- The output in the `join` contains all the individual counters *up to the current* level (E.g., to get `1.3.` instead of `1.3.0.0.0.0.` etc.)

Result for

```
from io import StringIO
text = StringIO(
'''
# Algorithms
This chapter covers the most basic algorithms.
## Sorting
Quicksort is fast and widely used in practice
Merge sort is a deterministic algorithm
## Searching
DFS and BFS are widely used graph searching algorithms
# Data Structures
more text
## more data structures
''')
```

is

```
['1. Algorithms',
 '1.1. Sorting',
 '1.2. Searching',
 '2. Data Structures',
 '2.1. more data structures']
```

Another, but similiar approach, without `defaultdict` would be:

```
levels = []
index = []
for line in text:
    if not line.startswith("#"):
        continue
    hashes, caption = line.rstrip().split(maxsplit=1)
    level = len(hashes)
    if level > len(levels):
        levels.append(1)
    else:
        levels[level-1] += 1
    levels = levels[:level]
    index.append(
        ".".join(str(l) for l in levels) + ". " + caption
    )
```

Comment: I understand until `level = len(hashes)` could you explain what is going on after ? thanks

Comment: @moth I have added some explanations (and an alternative which is a little bit simpler).

Comment: I don't understand how you came up with increasing `1` for every `level` in this loop: `for l in range(level + 1, max_level + 1):`

Comment: @moth Actually, for those `l`s there's no increase but a reset to `0`. Once a `level` is increased, all levels _"above"_ (or _"beyond"_) it must be set to `0`. If you have `1. -> 1.1. -> 1.2.` and then have to increase the first level (`1. -> 2.`), the second one needs to go to `0` - otherwise the next `##` would lead to `2.3.` instead of `2.1.`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def to_table(d, p = []):
   r, c, l = defaultdict(list), 0, None
   for a, *b in d:
      if a != '#' and p:
         yield f'{".".join(map(str, p))} {"".join(b)}'
      elif a == '#':
         r[l:=((c:=c+1) if b[0] != '#' else c)].append(''.join(b))
   yield from [j for a, b in r.items() for j in to_table(b, p+[a])]

s = """
# Algorithms
This chapter covers the most basic algorithms.
## Sorting
Quicksort is fast and widely used in practice
Merge sort is a deterministic algorithm
## Searching
DFS and BFS are widely used graph searching algorithms
# Data Structures
more text
## more data structures
"""
print('\n'.join(to_table(list(filter(None, s.split('\n'))))))
```

Output:

```
1 Algorithms
1.1 Sorting
1.2 Searching
2 Data Structures
2.1 more data structures
```

Comment: could you briefly explain the code ? interesting you're using the walrus operator, that's quite new feature in python.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of the top-level number and the sub-level number, and substitute the single hashes with the top level number and the double hashes with the format `top.sub`.

You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69709176/15938937)